# Inserting a new column for serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert-update, row-number

I have table with 500 records in it and want to insert new column as "serial number" starting with 1.

Comment: Do you care about the order the existing rows are assigned the serial number values? If so, could you please describe that requirement>

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the order in which the identity values are assigned, you are best off doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewTable
(
  SerialNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  ... other columns from original table ...
);

INSERT dbo.NewTable(...other columns...)
  SELECT ...other columns...
  FROM dbo.OriginalTable
  ORDER BY ...ordering criteria...
  OPTION (MAXDOP 1); -- to prevent parallelism from messing with identity

DROP TABLE dbo.OriginalTable;

EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.NewTable', N'OriginalTable', N'OBJECT';
```

You may have to deal with constraints etc. and you will want to do this in a transaction. The point is that just adding an identity column to the table with assign the identity values in an arbitrary order. If you don't care about how the existing values are assigned serial numbers, then just use Kyle's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved as follows:

```
alter table YourTable
add SrNo int identity(1,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

in PostgreSQL just do:
`ALTER TABLE ttaabbllee ADD COLUMN columnName serial NOT NULL;` and done!..

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server not postgres